# Calling a C++ function from C# by passing a string with variable size to it

Tags: c#, c++

I am calling a C++ function from C# code by passing a string to it. The C++ function is responsible for filling the string content. Following is the code:

C# side:

```
var abc = new StringBuilder(4096); // need to change this
var result = NativeMethods.SignCrcFile(abc);
```

C++ side:

```
bool __cdecl SignCrcFile(char* abc)
{
...
char* tempStr = "Hello All"; //for example
//copy it to abc string.
strcpy(abc,tempStr);
return true;
}
```

The problem is that the size of the tempStr in the C++ function is dynamic(the above assignment to tempStr is just an example). 
In such a case, it is not good idea to hard code the size of abc string on C# side to 4096 bytes.
One solution could be to create 2 functions on C++ side to get the size of the string first. Then allocate that size using StringBuilder in C# side. Then use the next function to get the entire string from C++ to C# side. But this may not be the most optimal way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stringbuilder has not been fixed to 4096 chars, it allows to hold up to 4096b initially, but the final size of the string when you do .ToString will be variable with a max length of 4096.

If you are afraid it will not be enough then you can raise it.

Else, you can add an int* to the function call and if the char* is null put the needed size on that int, in this way you can call the function one time without the stringbuilder, get the size, initialize it with such size and call again the function with the stringbuilder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an extra "int* StrLen" Parameter to the function and called the function twice from C#. Once by passing NativeMethods.SignCrcFile(null,out crcStrLen) and then creating a new string of crcStrLen size using stringbuilder and then called the function again like this NativeMethods.SignCrcFile(crc,out crcStrLen). From C++ side, I found the length of the string first in case string is NULL and in case it is not, simply perform copy of the previously captured string(kept this as static) and pass to C#.

Comment: You can also check the size on the second call to avoid buffer overruns